# Python Syntax Error when entering \ inside quotes

Tags: python

Line of code:

```
typewrite('C\Users\Arthur\Desktop\New folder\a'+picture[i]+'.png')
```

If I remove the \ from the code, the above works so I know the issue is with the \ symbol and do not remember why \ cannot be in quotes this way.

Syntax Error:

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-2: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Comment: can you show the data of `picture[i]`?

Comment: picture = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a7",
          "a6", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12"]

Comment: Someone already posted the answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\` has a special meaning. While giving a address you have to counter this special meaning. You could do one of the following:
Either:

```
typewrite('C\\\Users\\\Arthur\\\Desktop\\\New folder\\\a'+picture[i]+'.png')
```

That is, I have used double slashes.

Or,

```
typewrite(r'C\\Users\Arthur\Desktop\New folder\a'+picture[i]+'.png')
```

That is, put 'r' before 'C.... (don't use double slashes with this method)